# Blockchain suddenly stopped working

Tags: php

[Bitcoin stopped generating bitcoin address, It used to work 2 days before, Suddenly it stopped working. I think blockchain had made changes. Please help. I saw blockchain was upgrading. so They might have made some changes.

```js
<?php
/**
 *
 * @ EvolutionScript FULL DECODED & NULLED
 *
 * @ Version  : 5.1
 * @ Author   : MTIMER
 * @ Release on : 2014-09-01
 * @ Website  : http://www.mtimer.net
 *
 **/

if (!defined("EvolutionScript")) {
 exit("Hacking attempt...");
}


if ($_SESSION['logged'] != "yes") {
 header("location: ./");
 exit();
}

$blockchain_root = "https://blockchain.info/";

if (is_numeric($input->g['order'])) {
 $orderid = $db->real_escape_string($input->gc['order']);
 $chk = $db->fetchOne("SELECT COUNT(id) AS NUM FROM blockchain_requests WHERE id=" . $orderid . " 

AND user_id=" . $user_info['id']);

 if ($chk == 0) {
  header("location: ./?view=account");
  exit();
 }
 else {
  $bc_address = $db->fetchOne("SELECT account FROM gateways WHERE id=8");
  $order = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM blockchain_requests WHERE id=" . $orderid);
  $timeleft = TIMENOW - 10800;

  if ($order['bc_address'] == "" || $order['date'] < $timeleft) {
   $callback_url = $settings['site_url'] . "modules/gateways/bcstatus.php?order=" . 

$order['id'] . "&secret=" . $order['code'] . "&membership=" . $order['membership'];
   $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($blockchain_root . "api/receive?

method=create&callback=" . urlencode($callback_url) . "&address=" . $bc_address));
   $account_address = $response->input_address;
   $db->query("UPDATE blockchain_requests SET bc_address='" . $account_address . "', 

date=" . TIMENOW . (" WHERE id=" . $order['id']));
  }
  else {
   $account_address = $order['bc_address'];
  }

  require SMARTYLOADER;
  $smarty->assign("amount", $order['btc_amount']);
  $smarty->assign("account", $account_address);
  $smarty->assign("blockchain_root", $blockchain_root);
  $smarty->assign("file_name", "blockchain.tpl");
  $smarty->display("account.tpl");
  exit();
 }
}


if (is_numeric($input->p['amount']) && isset($input->p['type'])) {
 $amount = number_format($input->pc['amount'], 2, ".", "");

 if ($input->p['type'] == "deposit") {
  $minimum_deposit = $db->fetchOne("SELECT min_deposit FROM gateways WHERE id=8");

  if ($amount < $minimum_deposit) {
   exit("Error");
  }
 }

 $upgrade_id = (!is_numeric($input->p['membership']) ? 0 : $input->p['membership']);
 $btc_amount = file_get_contents($blockchain_root . "tobtc?currency=USD&value=" . $amount);
 $data = array("user_id" => $user_info['id'], "amount" => $amount, "btc_amount" => $btc_amount, "type" 

=> $input->pc['type'], "membership" => $upgrade_id, "code" => substr(md5("block" . TIMENOW . "bc"), 4, 15), 

"date" => TIMENOW);
 $db->insert("blockchain_requests", $data);
 $orderid = $db->lastInsertId();
 header("location: ./?view=blockchain&order=" . $orderid);
 exit();
 return 1;
}

header("location: ./?view=account");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you've run into [this problem (Blockchain if full)](https://medium.com/@octskyward/the-resolution-of-the-bitcoin-experiment-dabb30201f7).

Comment: what do you mean to say ,  i didn't understand what is full